# Resizing user icon on the server side in users page

Tags: feature-request, profile-picture, imgur, users-page, performance

Today I noticed that [a user's page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) shows a lot of user icons scaled from the very biggest ones. E.g. [rene's icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj33e.png?s=96&g=1) original size is 652'832 bytes, but actually it's scaled from 512 pixels × 512 pixels to 48 pixels × 48 pixels on the page.

Total page size is about 4 MB and [gtmetrix.com](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/meta.stackexchange.com/U3ZgT4tv) does not show a good page speed score for it.

Is it possible to resize user icons on the server side before they are received by the client browser?

Comment: All they need is to change `?s=96` to `?s=48`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj33e.png?s=48&g=1 (imgur already store several thumbnails with different size, 96x96 isn't one of them so it returns the original image)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd as far as I remember we already discuss something similar about imgur sizes.

Comment: Probably just about their existence, but the team need to change the code to use the correct size.

Comment: You like that picture, right?

Comment: @rene not enough, it should be full HD at least!

Comment: you are about to destroy a flower.